# How to select specific view model data to load in a specific view

Tags: windows-phone-7, mvvm

I'm not sure if I stated my question clearly, but I have two seperate pages and a single view model. Originally I only had one page, but I decided to split these up because my pages were getting too large (more specifically I had too many pivot items on a single page where two pages would seperate the data better for the user). I was wondering if it was possible to only load specific data to a single view from the view model, because as it is right now my application is freezing because my view model attempts to load all the data even though only about half of it needs to be used on the current page the user is viewing. If so, I'm assuming I would somehow need to let the view model know which data to load. How would I accomplish this. OR, is it good practice to create two seperate view models, one for each page, so that only the necessary data for each page will load accordingly and keep my application from freezing? I am not sure what the standard is here, or what is the most efficient in terms of CPU usage and response times, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loading more data than you need can definitely be a problem especially if you're doing it over the Internet. Why do it like that? Why not simply separate the viewmodel in two parts? The definition of VM basically says: (quote from [Model-View-ViewModel (MVVM) Explained](http://www.wintellect.com/cs/blogs/jlikness/archive/2010/04/14/model-view-viewmodel-mvvm-explained.aspx))

> The viewmodel is a key piece of the triad because it introduces Presentation Separation, or the concept of keeping the nuances of the view separate from the model. Instead of making the model aware of the user's view of a date, so that it converts the date to the display format, the model simply holds the data, the view simply holds the formatted date, and the controller acts as the liaison between the two.

If you separated the view, you might as well separate the VM too in order to keep things simple.

Still, if that doesn't do it for you and your data is not exposed as a service of some kind, why not just using the parts of VM? Call only the methods you need according to the page which you're seeing, set only the properties you need, don't do it all. And do it on a different thread if the data is really large to process so that your UI doesn't freeze (and of course, in the meantime show the user that you're getting the data using a progress bar).

That should be enough for the scenario you described.

Comment: Yes, thats exactly what I was thinking about doing. Thanks for your response. I am in fact loading data from the internet as well so I believe I will seperate my VM and see how that works out.

Comment: ..and it worked, just wanted to respond! by the way I love your blog on WP7 windows phone 8 should be very exciting to work with!